# How to fix this shower drain cover?

Tags: shower, drain, grout

I'm about to regrout my shower floor but I'm not sure if I need something else other than grout cement in order to fix the drain cover in place.

Any suggestion?

EDITED: what seems to be only a drain cover in the pictures, actually it's a cover with its housing. So once in place, if I need to service the drain, I can just need to screw off the cover

[image]
[image]

Comment: Use something that can be removed easily. Eventually you will have to remove it to get hair etc out of it. Mine always have had screws. While you are at it get a stainless steel cover that won't rust.

Comment: the cover is removable .. I'm not sure what to use to fix its housing in place

Answer (score 1):

Grout will not prevent water leaking down the drain pipe and creating problems

Recommended would be to use silicone that would also allow you to service the drain in the future.

Comment: Thank's for your reply. The cover can be screwed off once in place (question edited). i'm just not sure what I can use to fix its housing

Comment: Seal between the tile and the outside of the drain pipe, @Zedzdead, with caulk. Grout is _not_ waterproof. If you don't use a quality silicone caulk, you'll end up with (more) water leaking _outside_ the pipe and into whatever is below. BTW, have you checked below for water damage? Depending on how long this has been like this, it's likely there is some sort of damage below.